# Intent in an adapter using global variables from activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, adapter

I've been looking for an answer and I'm just turning around and around.
I'm trying to make my application work with google drive.
My problem is that I'm using an intent in an adapter called in a class and I would like to pass through the intent variables I got from another activity.

My inner class :

```
public class QueryFilesActivity extends BaseDemoActivity {

    private ListView mResultsListView;
    private ResultsAdapter mResultsAdapter;
    Date date = new Date();
    String stringDate = DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(date);
    String ecrire;
    String ville;
    String container;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle b) {
        super.onCreate(b);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_listfiles);
        mResultsListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewResults);
        mResultsAdapter = new ResultsAdapter(this);
        mResultsListView.setAdapter(mResultsAdapter);
        Intent i = getIntent();
        ecrire = i.getStringExtra("test");
        ville = i.getStringExtra("ville");
        container = i.getStringExtra("cont");
    }

    /**
     * Clears the result buffer to avoid memory leaks as soon
     * as the activity is no longer visible by the user.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mResultsAdapter.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        super.onConnected(connectionHint);
        Query query = new Query.Builder()
                .addFilter(Filters.eq(SearchableField.TITLE, stringDate+"_"+ville+2))
                .build();
        Drive.DriveApi.query(getGoogleApiClient(), query)
                .setResultCallback(metadataCallback);
    }

    final private ResultCallback<MetadataBufferResult> metadataCallback = new
            ResultCallback<MetadataBufferResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(MetadataBufferResult result) {
                    if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                        showMessage("Problem while retrieving results");
                        return;
                    }
                    mResultsAdapter.clear();
                    mResultsAdapter.append(result.getMetadataBuffer());
                }
            };
}
```

And my adapter :

```
public class ResultsAdapter extends DataBufferAdapter<Metadata> {


    public ResultsAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = View.inflate(getContext(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, null);
        }
        Metadata metadata = getItem(position);

        String resultat = metadata.getAlternateLink();
        String S1 = resultat.substring(32,60);
        TextView titleTextView =
                (TextView) convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        titleTextView.setText(S1);
        Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), EditContentsActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("file", S1);



        getContext().startActivity(intent);


        return convertView;
    }

}
```

I would like to pass what I get in my intent in the intent of my adapter.
Any suggestion?

Comment: You need to pull values out of the activity's intent, and put them in a bundle?  What's the problem?  I see you are doing both of those things in your code already.

Comment: Yeah, seems you are already implementing the necessary to send and retrieve data on the intent, is there some error ?

Comment: I would like to put what I get in my activity in the intent inside of the adapter to pass to the EditcontentsActivity.I'm a litlle bit lost...or maybe I can retrieve it directly?I just don't know how to do

Answer (score 0):

I just forgot to put my third class to record stuff in my drive.

```
public class EditContentsActivity extends BaseDemoActivity {
String saver;
String numero;
String file;
String ville;


private static final String TAG = "EditContentsActivity";

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    super.onConnected(connectionHint);

    final ResultCallback<DriveApi.DriveIdResult> idCallback = new ResultCallback<DriveApi.DriveIdResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(DriveApi.DriveIdResult result) {
            if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                showMessage("Cannot find DriveId. Are you authorized to view this file?");
                return;
            }
            DriveId driveId = result.getDriveId();
            DriveFile file = driveId.asDriveFile();
            new EditContentsAsyncTask(EditContentsActivity.this).execute(file);
        }
    };
    Intent i = getIntent();
    file = i.getStringExtra("file");
    ville = i.getStringExtra("localite");

    Drive.DriveApi.fetchDriveId(getGoogleApiClient(), file)
            .setResultCallback(idCallback);
}

public class EditContentsAsyncTask extends ApiClientAsyncTask<DriveFile, Void, Boolean> {

    public EditContentsAsyncTask(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackgroundConnected(DriveFile... args) {
        DriveFile file = args[0];
        try {
            DriveApi.DriveContentsResult driveContentsResult = file.open(
                    getGoogleApiClient(), DriveFile.MODE_READ_WRITE, null).await();
            if (!driveContentsResult.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                return false;
            }
            Intent i = getIntent();
            saver = i.getStringExtra("test");
            numero = i.getStringExtra("cont");
            double e1 = i.getDoubleExtra("lat", 0);
            double e2 = i.getDoubleExtra("longi", 0);

            DriveContents driveContents = driveContentsResult.getDriveContents();
            ParcelFileDescriptor parcelFileDescriptor = driveContents.getParcelFileDescriptor();
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(parcelFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor());
            fileInputStream.read(new byte[fileInputStream.available()]);
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(parcelFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor());
            Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(fileOutputStream);
            writer.write("\n container "+numero+" : "+saver+"\nlatitude : "+e1+" longitude : "+e2+ville);
            writer.close();
            fileOutputStream.close();
            //OutputStream outputStream = driveContents.getOutputStream();
            //outputStream.write("Hello world".getBytes());
            com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status status =
                    driveContents.commit(getGoogleApiClient(), null).await();
            return status.getStatus().isSuccess();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "IOException while appending to the output stream", e);
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        if (!result) {
            showMessage("Error while editing contents");
            return;
        }
        showMessage("les données ont bien été enregistrées");
    }
}
```

}
what's happening is that my variables are null